# Degrees of a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If $G$ is a graph with girth $\ge 5$ on $n$ vertices, I have to show the following:

(i) Why for each vertex $x$, $\sum \limits_{y \text{ a neighbor of $x$} } deg(y) \le n-1$

(ii) Show $\sum \limits_{x \in V(G) } (deg(x))^2 \le n(n-1)$

FOr (ii) we know that $deg(x) \le n$ for any $x$. If we keep adding the degrees of other vertices, they have to be one less than $n$. This makes sense intuitively to obtain a bound of $n(n-1)$, but how can it be shown mathematically? I feel we can use (i) somehow?

Please help! Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- What would happen if two neighbors $y$, $z$ of $x$ had a common neighbor other than $x$, that is, $\mathcal{N}(y) \cap \mathcal{N}(z) \supsetneq \{x\}$?
- Consider $\sum_{x \in V}\sum_{y \in \mathcal{N}(x)} \deg(y)$, change summation order and use the inequality from $(i)$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$